# How can I extract a file path from a Perl string?

Tags: regex, perl, path

I want to find the file name with fullpath from this string

```
"[exec] /snschome/sns/ccyp/mb_ccsns/bb/cbil5/v85_8/amdocs/iamcust/bil/cl/business/handlers/ClReportsHandler.java:233: cannot resolve symbol"
```

I want to extract

```
/snschome/sns/ccyp/mb_ccsns/bb/cbil5/v85_8/amdocs/iamcust/bil/cl/business/handlers/ClReportsHandler.java
```

and I am trying this in Perl

```
    $_=$string_from_to_match
    my @extract_file=split(/.*(\/.*)\:.*/);
    print $extract_file[1],"\n";`
```

but I am getting this output:

```
/ClReportsHandler.java:233:
```

It is matching the last `/` and the last `:`. How can I change it to first `/`  and first `:`?

Comment: Please edit the formatted version instead of rolling back to the unformatted one. Otherwise your question is unreadable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a case where “tacking and stretching” is useful. You know that `[exec]` followed by whitespace is on the left and colon followed by a line number is on the right. You want what's in between:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

$_ = "[exec] /snschome/sns/ccyp/mb_ccsns/bb/cbil5/v85_8/amdocs/iamcust/bil/cl/business/handlers/ClReportsHandler.java:233: cannot resolve symbol";

if (/\[exec\]\s*(.+?):\d+/) {
  print $1, "\n";
}
```

Comment: hi it worked & from your regular expression i changed mine like this & it is working fine .. my <pre>@extract_file=split(/.*?(\/.*?)\:.*/); </pre>

Answer (score 1):

If your file name doesn't contain spaces then you can create simple regexp to match all parts:

```
my ($file, $line, $msg) = ( $string_from_to_match =~ m{(\S+):([^:]+):([^:]+)} );
```

I've used:

- `\S+` to match 1 or more non-space symbols
- `[^:]+` to match 1 or more not `:` symbols

If you want spaces in path, then the best way is to remove starting `[exec]` part and split by `:`:

```
$string_from_to_match =~ s{^\[exec\]\s+}{};
my ($file, $line, $msg) = split(/:/, $string_from_to_match, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.10.1;

my $str = "[exec] /snschome/sns/ccyp/mb_ccsns/bb/cbil5/v85_8/amdocs/iamcust/bil/cl/business/handlers/ClReportsHandler.java:233: cannot resolve symbol";
$str =~ s!^[^/]*(/[^:]*):.*$!$1!;
say $str;
```

Ouput:
    /snschome/sns/ccyp/mb_ccsns/bb/cbil5/v85_8/amdocs/iamcust/bil/cl/business/handlers/ClReportsHandler.java

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using `split()` if you want to match?

```
if ($subject =~ m!(/[^:]+):!) {
    $result = $1;
} else {
    $result = "";
}
```

should do it.

Explanation:

`!`: alternative regex delimiter (since I need the `/` inside)

`(`: start capturing group

`/`: match a `/`. This will always be the first `/` of the string.

`[^:]+`: match 1 or more characters except `:`

`)`: end capturing group

`:`: match a `:`

`!`: regex delimiter

Answer (score -1):

This is what I do:

```
if ($fullpath =~ /^(.+)\/([^\/]+)/)
{
    my ($path, $file) = ($1, $2);
}
```

This works by matching anything except the last /.  This may not work under Windows of course.