# Regex to identify a full path name

Tags: regex, perl, pathname

I have data where some lines may contain a full path name in the second field.  I need to identify such a line.

I found "[*How can I extract a file path from a Perl string?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761211/how-can-i-extract-a-file-path-from-a-perl-string)" but I've just given up trying.

I'm sticking to path names with alphanumerics, underscores, dashes, and dots, with components separated by slashes `/`.

I want to recognize these examples as path names:

- `/abc/qwert_yu.1234/now_at_file.name4`
- `/_.123/zaqe/0987_123.666/how_deep/can-I-go`

Each component should match a pattern like `qr(^[\w\.\-]+$)`, and I have this working.

My problem is with matching a path that contains any number of segments, each preceded by a forward slash.

I tried many permutations on this:

```
$dir_pat = qr(/($fpat))
```

When I test

```
p "/qwe.123_545-FFF" =~ $dir_pat
```

it just does not match.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not your blog. Please follow the advice given in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: provide example(s) of your subject. e.g. are you trying to get the path from a full url? buried within some larger arbitrary text? etc.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your are asking why the following doesn't match.

```
my $fpat = qr(^[\w\.\-]+$);
my $dir_pat = qr(/($fpat));
"/qwe.123_545-FFF" =~ $dir_pat
```

Captures aside, your pattern is the following:

```
/^[\w\.\-]+$
```

So you are trying to match a `/` followed by the start of a string. That will never match. You want

```
^/[\w\.\-]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the anchors around the entire pattern, not around each path segment

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

for my $path (
    '/abc/qwert_yu.1234/now_at_file.name4',
    '/_.123/zaqe/0987_123.666/how_deep/can-I-go' ) {

    say "ok" if $path =~ m|^(?:/[\w.-]+)+$|;
}
```

#### output

```
ok
ok
```

Comment: Borodin, I have given you kudos in my code.  I've never seen that ?: construct.  This is a "non marking grouping". Put that into a google search for additional information.

Comment: @JacobSalomon: That's an unusual name for it. [The Perl documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Non-capturing-groupings) calls it a non-capturing group. If you are running perl v5.22.0 or later then you can use the *Non-Capturing Regular Expression Flag* `/n` to disable capturing on *all* parentheses, so `say "ok" if $path =~ m|^(/[\w.-]+)+$|n` will also work.